# Remove files less than n lines in Perl

Tags: perl, unix

I'm writing a Perl script to remove files that have fewer than a given number of lines. What I have so far is

```
my $cmd = join('','wc -l ', $file); #prints number of lines to command line
if (system($cmd) < 4)
{
  my $rmcmd = join('','rm ',$file);
  system($rmcmd);
}
```

where `$file` is the name and location of a file.

Comment: Did you ask a question?

Comment: There's no need to call `system` to remove a file.  Use the `unlink` function in Perl itself.  Also, instead of `join('','wc -l ', $file)` you can just say `"wc -l $file"`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use `system` for this. Perl is perfectly capable of counting lines:

```
sub count_lines { 
    open my $fh, '<', shift;        
    while(local $_ = <$fh>) {}  # loop through all lines
    return $.;
}

unlink $file if count_lines($file) < 4;
```

I'm assuming your end goal is to have it search through a directory tree removing files with line count less than *n*. Check out [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Find) and its nifty code generator `find2perl` to handle that part for you.

Comment: Alternatively: `my $count = () = <FILE>;`

Comment: @Zaid: That will unnecessarily read the entire file into memory.